# Syntax highlighting in vim for python

Tags: python, vim, syntax, vi, vim-syntax-highlighting

How do I do I set the syntax highlighting in Vim 7 for python?

I would like to set my own colorschemes, and syntax highlighting for a type of code file.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

The command to enable syntax highlighting in vim is `:syntax on`, if you want it to be active everytime you launch vim, just add a line containing `syntax on` in your .vimrc file.

If you're already editing a Python file and syntax highlighting wasn't on, after enabling syntax highlighting (as above) then: `:set filetype=python`

Comment: maybe your vim doesn't have filetype detection enabled, try adding `filetype on` to your `.vimrc` or type `:set filetype=python` while editing a file.

Comment: i think that vim is broken becuse :help gives E433: No tags file
E149: Sorry, no help for vi_help.txt
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: maybe try reinstalling it, either with your package manager or from sources, never had these errors, can't help you for this.

Comment: thanks anyway it may have something to do with useing "..The vim-minimal package includes a minimal version of VIM,...." according to package manager

Comment: Pretty hard to detect a filetype unless  it reads the first line of the file.  I never use extensions for commands.  filetype=python seems to work.

Comment: @hidroto `vim-tiny` by default provides no help, or any of the truly powerful features of vim.

Comment: None of this works for me. Tried adding `filetype on` and `syntax on` on `.vimrc`, also `:set filetype=python` while editing the file, and added the shebang as suggested elsewhere :(

Comment: @hidroto, a tag file must be created independently of Vim.  One easy option is to use a program like Exuberant Ctags, which will do it for a whole directory tree in one quick command.  See the Vim docs (which are good) at http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_29.html#29.1, and https://vimways.org/2018/you-should-be-using-tags-in-vim/.

Comment: for noobs not knowing the location of `.vimrc` file, here you go: `echo "syntax on" >> ~/.vimrc`

Answer (score 14):

Put the line `syntax on` in your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 9):

1. Verify that you have the latest version of vim, equally execute `sudo apt-get install vim`
2. Modify the `.vimrc` file with the instruction `echo "syntax on" >> ~/.vimrc`
3. Open the file with `vi app.py`. You will see the **Syntax highlighting**

[image]

Comment: this is the answer for my case, tx

Answer (score 1):

If you're on *nix system (linux, macos) or cygwin and if you already have vim `:set syntax` set but your filename doesn't end with `.py` you can add a shebang to the first line of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Next time you open the file in vim, you should see syntax highlighting. Note this will work for other file types, you just use the interpreter name i.e. `(python, ruby, sh)`